# ¿Como cambiar idioma de todos los mensajes de error de asp.net mvc del ingles al español?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Cambiando el formulario de registro de usuarios que trae por default asp.net mvc5 me percate que los mensajes de error que mandaba venían en ingles:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estos errores se muestran en el Resumen de validación (**ValidationSummary**)
al buscar por Internet lo único que encontré son varias respuestas del sitio hermano  en ingles como la [siguiente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961648/how-to-localize-asp-net-identity-username-and-password-error-messages) que no solucionaban el error ya que solo traducía algunos errores, como podría traducir todos los mensajes de error al español que se muestran en los formularios como el de registro ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instalar el paquete de idioma en español en Manage Nuget Packages
llamado

> Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.core.es

posterior a eso se tiene que agregar la siguiente linea dentro de `system.web` en `web.config` del proyecto

> ```
> <globalization culture="es-MX" uiCulture="es" />
> ```

para que todos los mensajes de error aparezcan en español

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]